# expected an indented block (views.py, line 12)

Tags: python, sql-server, django

Estoy haciendo una conexión a Sql Server con PYODBC 
Desde la consola si me conecta y todo pero cuando lo hago desde el proyecto me aparecen varios errores que he solucionado, pero con este no he podido resolverlo

Alguien me pudiera orientar?

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.7
Python Version: 2.7.14
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')
```

Error:

```
Traceback:
File "C:\dev\Venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  98.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "C:\dev\Venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  338.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\dev\Venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  367.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\dev\Venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  361.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "C:\dev\clienteServidor-master\mysite\urls.py" in <module>
  7.     url(r'', include('blog.urls')),
File "C:\dev\Venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py" in include
  28.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "C:\dev\clienteServidor-master\blog\urls.py" in <module>
  2. from . import views

Exception Type: IndentationError at /
Exception Value: expected an indented block (views.py, line 12)
```

Comment: Descargue el proyecto de internet, debido a que en mi otro proyecto tampoco pude consultar la información

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya di con el problema. es por que estaba mal estructurado :/

ERROR:

```
def post_list(request):
con=pyodbc......

Forma correcta:
def post_list(request):
   con=pyodbc......
```